Counting irreducible Permutations
Let $x:=(x_1,...,x_n)$ be a permutation of $\{1,...,n\}$.
We say, $x$ is irreducible iff $\{x_1,...,x_m\}\neq\{1,...,m\}$ for $1\leq m \leq n-1$.
Let $g(n)$ be the number of irreduible permutations of $\{1,...,n\}$.
Define $G$ to be $G(z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n!z^n$.
Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g(n)z^n=1-\frac{1}{G(z)}$.
I am new to formal power series and I am trying to do some exercises regarding this topic. My problem is that I don't know how to do this exercise. I have no idea how to count those irreducible permutations.

Clarification requested: Does the posted question intend that a permutation is irreducible if and only if, for each $~m \in {1,2,\cdots,n-1},~$ you have that $~{x_1,\cdots,x_m} \neq {1,2,\cdots,m} ~?$

@user2661923 Yes exactly. Maybe another way to say would be if ${x_1,..,x_m}={1,...,m}$ only if $m=n$.

Given a permutation $x$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, if it is not irreducible, there must be some $m<n$ such that $\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}=\{1,\ldots,m\}$. We define the maximum $m$ as $I(x)$. Note $I(x)=m$ iff $\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}=\{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $x_{m+1},\ldots,x_n$ is an irreducible permutation of $\{m+1,\ldots,n\}$, so the number of permutations $x$ such that $I(x)=m$ can be computed as $m!\cdot g(n-m)$. Hence,
$$g(n)=n!-\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m!\cdot g(n-m).\quad(1)$$
Now consider the power series $G(z) \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g(n)z^n$. The coefficient of $z^k$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}n!\cdot g(k-n)$, which equals to $g(k)+\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}n!\cdot g(k-n)$, i.e., $k!$ by our formula $(1)$. Hence, we have $$G(z) \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g(n)z^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n!\cdot z^n=G(z)-1,$$
which means
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g(n)z^n = 1-\frac{1}{G(z)}$.
